# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLik when I save a excel file

Tags: python, path

This is my code and try to save the output.
But I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jovyan/./main.py", line 26, in <module>
 input_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(input_path, filename))
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLik
```

............

if **name** == '**main**':

```
  for filename in os.listdir(input_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
      input_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(str(input_path), filename))
      
      result.to_csv(os.path.join(str(output_path), filename))
```

Comment: what does `anomaly_detector()` do? is `result` a dataframe?

Comment: yes, return dataframe

Comment: Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help formatting code in your post.